# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) BUT i provide 2 values

Tags: python, for-loop, text-files

Im working on this code that simply adds new data into a text file, and i had it working but then i ran it once more and it produced the errer "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)". I know what this error means its just that i seem to provide two values? i must be missing something thats wrong?

The code where it produces an error:

```
schoolnames=[]
scores=[]
with open("Cdrive.txt","r")as a_file:
     for x in a_file.readlines():
         data=x.strip()   #Im aware i could just use data, but i use X to try fix the error, of course this didnt work 
         print(data)
         school,score=data.split(",") #The error is produced here
         schoolnames.append(school)
         scores.append(score)
```

My text file looks like this (there are no lines between each bit of data in the text file):

sjp,15

chelmer,10

newhall,20

Comment: can you please indent your code?

Comment: Sounds like you have an empty line somewhere in your file.

Comment: Your code runs fine for me when I use those three lines you provided. Most likely you have a blank line somewhere in your text file. Try printing a loop index along with data to track what line you are on before you get the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have blank lines, you can make it work just add one condition checking:

`if data` would be false if you apply strip() on a blank line. you can check whether comma in the stripped line

```
 for x in a_file.readlines():
     data=x.strip()
     if data and "," in data:  
         school,score=data.split(",")
```

Comment: yep, I had an empty line. Never would have checked, thanks.